# How to change html elements with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I just started my first angularjs app and have been trying to solve what seems like should be a straight forward problem.  I have a form like this:

`<form>
    <label>Title</label><input type="text" name="title" value="Title"><input type="checkbox" name="listType" value="unordered">Unordered
    <ol>
        <li><label>First</label><input type="text" name="first" value="Temp1"></li>
        <li><label>Second</label><input type="text" name="second" value="Temp2"></li>
        <li><label>Third</label><input type="text" name="third" value="Temp3"></li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form>`

Now what I was hoping to accomplish is that if the checkbox is checked the `<ol>` would become a `<ul>` and vice versa when it is unchecked.  How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: you are looking for [angular directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: simpler to just change the class using `ng-class` and set list-style in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"value" is the wrong attribute to use. Use ng-model="unordered" instead and you'll get the benefit of data-binding.

Also, use ng-class as charlietfl said.